# How to put rails data into a javascrip array

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a collection of data coming from rails db but I want to convert it into a js array.

The array below is static, so I want to take the value of latitude and longitude from my rails application and convert it into an array like the one bellow.

```
var locations = [
        {lat: -31.563910, lng: 147.154312},
        {lat: -33.718234, lng: 150.363181},
        {lat: -33.727111, lng: 150.371124},
        {lat: -33.848588, lng: 151.209834},
        {lat: -33.851702, lng: 151.216968},]
```

I tried :

```
var locations = <%= raw @locations.to_json %>;
```

But it brings even what I don't need!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the result you are looking for?

```
<% count = @locations.count %>
var locations = [
  <% @locations.each_with_index do |loc, idx| %>
    {<%= loc.lat %>, <%= loc.lang %>}<% unless idx + 1 == count %>,<% end %>
  <% end %>
];
```

Comment: Yesss, it is! but the thing is that from each output it is automatically included a " ; ", for example " {lat:15252.122, lng:1424.222}; " instead of a simple comma ( {lat:15252.122, lng:1424.222}, ) and it makes the output not be loaded!

Comment: ok, I updated my code to fix that, now there should be a comma after, and it should not print one out on the last element.

Answer (score 0):

what is the format of the data coming from db? a JSON?
In that case you should:

```
var locations = JSON.parse( <%= raw @locations.to_json %> );
```

Comment: It comes as a hash

Comment: ok, I never used hash, but you can try this: var strData = ‘[
  <% @locations.each do |loc| %>
    {<%= loc.lat %>, <%= loc.lang %>};
  <% end %>
]‘; strData = strData.replace(/;/g, ‘,’); var locations = eval(strData);

Comment: Everything works fine but for some reason the replacement does not work ;(

Comment: Do you used apostrophes before and after [ ] ? It’s necessry you have var strData = ‘[...]’;

Comment: Yeaa, I did use it!

Answer (score 0):

Is it required to build a JS array of objects from the collection?

You can also use JSON an OpenStruct libs for this.

```
require 'JSON'
arr = JSON.parse(@locations.to_json, object_class: OpenStruct)
```

Then you can manage the array as a JS object.

If you wish to build a JS array, you can use something like Rockwells solution

```
var locations = []
<% @locations.each do |loc| %>
  locations.push({lat: "<%= loc.lat %>", lng: "<%= loc.lang %>"});
<% end %>
```